# getting undefined error with a express request that is grabbing data from a file

Tags: javascript, express

I have a express endpoint that grabs json object from a file and it is throwig an undefined when I console.log it... here is my endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');
const { events }  = require('../../assets/schedules');
const app = express();

app.get('/schedules', function (req, res) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(events));
  res.send(JSON.stringify(events));
});
```

events has `[{}, {}]`

Comment: Do you mean `events` has that value when the code is run, or that is the contents of the JSON file?

Comment: What happens if you put `console.log(events)` right after the `require` line?